# android - measuring altitude and accuracy on gps?

Tags: android, gps, altitude

In my android project I can get the accuracy and altitude measured, and they return an integer (or rather a float), but I don't understand how to use the value. Is the altitude measured in meters from ground level? and what about the accuracy, does it mean +- x meters?

Answer (score 0):

The altitude is the altitude above the WGS84 reference ellipsoid in meters. More information is provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432382/1127492