# Negative altitude value

Tags: android, gps, altitude

I am getting negative altitude value when finding latitude , longitude and altitude. Can anyone help me to find the reason for it ?

Comment: @Lucifer I am new to this site and I don't have enough reputation to accept the answer..

Comment: you dont any reputation to accept an answer, just tick the "tick" mark for most suitable answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Negative latitude and longitude values are to be expected. Since latitude is calculated from the equator, everything in the southern hemisphere will be negative. Same goes for longitude and the prime meridian, heading west from there is negative until you've gone halfway around the planet.

However, altitudes can also be negative because it's *possible* to be below the zero-altitude level. Short of seeing the code which produces your values, there's not much to be offered beyond general knowledge of how it works, so I'll cover that below.

GPS altitudes generally use a geodetic model for an idealised sea level (the zero altitude), basically mapping an ellipsoid onto the (less-than-perfectly-shaped) planet, which varies anyway with things such as lunar tidal forces. See [WGS84 here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) for more details.

The normal error expected is about +/- 15m, and this only applies about 95% of the time. According to the specs, the other 5% can have an altitude of *any* value.

And, of course, if your GPS doesn't have an unobstructed pathway between it and the satellites, the error range may be greater.

These potential errors are no doubt why aircraft rely on altimeters, ILS (instrument landing systems), or radar/laser ground reflections, for their near-ground activities. Or, preferably, all of those methods so that you can ignore outliers.

As one site puts it:

> What this means is that if you are walking on the seashore and see your altitude as -15 meters, you should not be too concerned.

Of course, if you're having troubles breathing, you may want to look more closely at how wet you are :-)

Comment: Haha. "the other 5% of the time can have an altitude of *any* value" -- this precise?

Answer (score 3):

Well, altitude in context of GPS coordinates represents your elevation according to the sea level. So I assume your current position is just below the sea level. Yeah, this is possible ;)

Comment: Or it could just be a bug with the data/calculations, but since no code was given/shown .. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The GPS altitude is the altitude above the GPS WGS84 reference elipsoid (which is different from sea level and does not take hills into account!). A negative altutude means (if it not due to a bad signal) that you are below the reference elipsoid.

Here is more information on how to get more accurate altitude: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432382/1127492

Answer (score 0):

Switch positioning settings to use Geoid model.