# Is it possible to get DEPTH using GPS in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to get accurate altitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361870/android-how-to-get-accurate-altitude)

I am creating application in that there are two phones.... Let's say.. there are 3 floor building... one phone in on 2nd' floor let's say it's name is **A** and another phone is on 1st' floor let's say it's name **B**

Now **A** is sending GPS location to **B** and something value from that phone **B** can be able to know that phone **A** is on **B**'s above or below... Like **A** phone can be able to send value like **+3M (meter)** so it's above to **B** and like **-3M (meter)** it's below to **B** is it possible using GPS???

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Only your posistion (latitude and longitude grid)

Comment: As far as i know, GPS cannot give depth... Cause it's work on co-ordinates,