# Smart tape measuring in Blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, sensors

**smart measuring tape in Blackberry 6 and 7.**

I want to measures the Distance and Height of a target by trigonometry using camera. I found this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.sira.measure) in google play.
I want to make this type of application not exactly same but quite same but for my requirement

Can anyone give me/suggest me the right way or any example so that I can get more idea about this requirement.

**This image will give you my clear requirement [image]**

**OR click this video link to understand the requirements [video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/B-kIY3TJSLc?ps).**

```
i want to get height of object and distance (c) .
```

Answer (score 1):

First step for this app should be to get angle to which point mobile(camera) is inclined. If it is possible to get inclined angle a,
then as per your given link by formula of tangent you will get distance of the object from the camera , here you have to consider cameras height(h).Once you get height then again incline your mobile to the top of the object,and  calculate height.

**In  short most important step is to get angle of inclination of the mobile to the object, after that all remaining part is trigonometric calculations.**

After all it will give approximate results not accurate.

[image]

> If you are able to calculate angle to which mobile is inclined
>
> Step First: calculate distance

1) Incline your mobile to the bottom of the object it will give you angle A(as shown in diagram)
2) consider height h at what you have held your mobile (consider standard as 5ft ) or

> You may use SONAR system to get height where you have held the phone or [this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361870/android-how-to-get-accurate-altitude)

3) Now by formula of tangent you will get distance d as shown in figure

> Step 2: Calculate height

1) Incline your mobile to the top of the object and get angle B as shown in figure.
2) As you have calculated d in previous step, put the angle b and d in tangent formula you will get h1
3) Add h and h1, you will get height of the object

Comment: Are you sure this correct? "If it is possible to get inclined angle a, then as per your given link by formula of tangent you will get distance of the object".  Even if you know the angle, don't you need to know the distance to get the height, or the height to get the distance?  Just as a for example, let me say the angle B is 30 degrees. What is the distance?

Comment: @PeterStrange ,yes i am sure to get distance of the object, you have assume height(where u have held the phone for e.g. you can consider it as 5 ft avg. height) and you will get the distance.

Comment: @swapnil7  i am getting angle now how can i detect the object from camera and get the height?

Comment: @swapnil7 which link you taking about and what you are trying to explain?

Comment: @askquestion got answer?

Comment: @askquestion now what is problem?

Comment: @swapnil7 not able to get height?

Comment: @askquestion my answer is giving clarification about how to get height

Comment: @swapnil7 your answer consider height h at what you have held your mobile (consider standard as 5ft ) i don' want to hard code height i want to get it from sensor like i am getting angle from device.

Comment: @askquestion now that is the only challenge remaining for your question, need to search about how to get height where your phone is held. In the first prototype of your application you may use avg. height.Please Tell me if i am wrong/correct in my solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48750/discussion-between-askquestion-and-swapnil7)