# Android: can measure gravity from distance above sea using type_gravity sensor?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've interest to measure distance from different level in building using android resources (Gravity sensor) or any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: The sensor noise is probably many orders of magnitude greater than the actual difference in gravity over the height of a building.  Even if the sensor were capable of this kind of precision, the device would have to be absolutely still... probably bolted to a giant piece of concrete.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for you note, but i would measure how high from level of the sea.. any source code or article may help

Comment: I feel like this is one of those implementations that, if it were realistically possible to accomplish with any accuracy, would be implemented by default with the sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Even if an android device had the precision nessacary to measure small changes like building floors, earth isn't perfectly round so the gravity can be about 0.02 m/s^2 more or less in different places, which is much more the change from just one building floor. You should try to get the altitude over GPS. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361870/android-how-to-get-accurate-altitude) is a post that might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Even at the top of Everest, your looking at a acceleration delta three orders of magnitude below a G.

> 9km/6300km  (Everest ht/ earth radius) = .0014

You will have a very hard time pulling relevant data at that precision with the average android device. Here's a reference that might be helpful though...

[Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation)