# Negative Altitude value in Android

Tags: android

I'm getting negative Altitude value even when I'm on 6 storey building . I initially thought my code was wrong, so I've downloaded couple of apps from play store. Even it is showing negative value.

My location is

> Chennai, Tamilnadu, India

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at this? I'm not an expert on GPS, but the two points in the answer here are likely to be the issue.
[Android: How to get accurate altitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361870/android-how-to-get-accurate-altitude)

Comment: Thanks Alex finally I got the correct Altitude information and I'm 28meters above sea level In Urapakkam,Chennai,

Answer (score 0):

Your device is getting poor GPS results for some reason, possibly due to hardware limitations or firmware bugs. Contact the device manufacturer for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just googled around a little bit and this is what I've found about **Chennai**:

> Elevation  6 m (20 ft)

The first thing that pops in my mind is that this is **average** elevation, which probably means that there are some parts of the city way above that, and also some parts that are below the sea level, even by 10-15m (which is roughly the height of the 6th floor).

This, combined with high margin for error of GPS altitude measurement **(+/- 15m)**, might have resulted in your seeing the negative altitude.

I might be wrong though, this is just my initial idea. You can test it by climbing a nearby hills or mountains, such as [according to google]
**Pallavaram Mountain**.

Answer (score 0):

GPS readings of altitudes aren't always accurate and have an error within about +/- 15 meters (50 feet) 95% of the time. GPS depends on clear and unobstructed view or it cannot make accurate range measurements to the satellites and hence the error.
So I would say to take the GPS readings with a grain of salt.

I am not sure what you plan to use the data for , but I would suggest you to normalize the readings you get over a period of time and use it.

Here's the [source](http://gpsinformation.net/main/altitude.htm)

Usually map data provides the average altitude levels of a given region, you can perhaps account that as a base value and compute relatively accurate altitudes.