# Use smartphone sensors' to detect user's floor level from a building

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm trying to create an android application for indoor mapping. So all I want is to detect when a user has changed the floor level using sensors(detection of the current level having as reference the level 0 of building). I assumed that the easiest way would be the detecting of the movement on an escalator or elevator.
Available sensors:

*-Accelerometer
-Gyroscope
-Magnetometer
-Gravity sensor
-Linear acceleration
-Rotation sensor*

I have searched that a good way is to combine the accelerometer and the gyroscope, but can that be applied in practice when user is on a slow escalator?
Theoretically if I know that the escalator deliver a client from a level to another in 10 seconds, the smartphone can record some specific sensor changes and to estimate that the user has changed the build level(upper or lower).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to get accurate altitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361870/android-how-to-get-accurate-altitude)

Comment: I have read this post. Nope, I'm trying to use smartphone's sensors as autonomic way to determine the floor level. GPS... Is not efficient. Elipsoid level, not accurate. Bu thank you.

Comment: Please experiment with sensor data, but mobile device sensors are noisy: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+noisy+sensor and getting accurate indoor location position without 802.11mc required additional sensors as in Project Tango: https://youtu.be/k43xJs3Roqg

Comment: Hey, it would be much better and faster if you will use pressure sensor. But in your case you will need to find the phone with this sensor.

Comment: I want to create an application that is simple to use on a simple device, that is equipped with basic sensors.