Get GPS altitude as MSL in .NET MAUI
I have a .NET MAUI project where i want to find the height above the ground for an android device. I found the Geolocation API where i can query the altitude in WGS84 reference system. I could not find any APIs providing a heightmap of the world in WGS84, the only APIs i could find expose the MSL for some coordinates.
In the Android Java API, there is an getMslAltitudeMeters() that should return the necessary value (i guess?). It seems as there isn't a corresponding method in MAUI. Am i missing something? Is there a intended way to solve this in MAUI?

You can always access the underlying platform API if MAUI doesn’t provide the abstraction you need

You can refer to Altitude and Android latitude.

@liyu All links provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361870/android-how-to-get-accurate-altitude/9432382#9432382 are either not providing any useful information or are no longer available

Accessing the platfom API itself is working quite well, but i get Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'The Mean Sea Level altitude of this location is not set.'
But i would consider this out of scope for this question

Not all location values may be available .For example,the Altitude property might be null,have a value of 0,or have a positive value indicating the meters above sea level.You can refer to Altitude.

@liyu I've create a second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79024786/android-location-mean-sea-level-not-set for that problem

Firstly, please test it in physical devices to make a test. Then you can grant the location permission in the settings manually. And you get the height in the LocationChange method, please push a Toast in this method to make sure this LocationChange executed. In the end, before you execute  getMslAltitudeMeters, please execute hasMslAltitude(), will you get true value?

How would i test it in physical devices? What do you mean by pushing a Toast?
