# WGS84 Geoid Height Altitude Offset for external GPS data on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gps, wgs84

For an application I'm writing we are interfacing IOS devices with an external sensor which outputs GPS data over a local wifi network.  This data comes across in a "raw" format with respect to altitude.  In general all GPS altitude needs to have a correction factor applied related to the WGS84 geoid height based on the current location.

For example, in the following Geo Control Point (http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/ds_mark.prl?PidBox=HV9830) which resides at Lat **38 56 36.77159** and a Lon **077 01 08.34929**

```
HV9830* NAD 83(2011) POSITION- 38 56 36.77159(N) 077 01 08.34929(W)   ADJUSTED  
HV9830* NAD 83(2011) ELLIP HT-    42.624 (meters)        (06/27/12)   ADJUSTED
HV9830* NAD 83(2011) EPOCH   -  2010.00
HV9830* NAVD 88 ORTHO HEIGHT -    74.7    (meters)     245.    (feet) VERTCON   
HV9830  ______________________________________________________________________
HV9830  GEOID HEIGHT    -        -32.02  (meters)                     GEOID12A
HV9830  NAD 83(2011) X  -  1,115,795.966 (meters)                     COMP
HV9830  NAD 83(2011) Y  - -4,840,360.447 (meters)                     COMP
HV9830  NAD 83(2011) Z  -  3,987,471.457 (meters)                     COMP
HV9830  LAPLACE CORR    -         -2.38  (seconds)                    DEFLEC12A
```

You can see that the Geoid Height is **-32 meters**.  So given a RAW GPS reading near this point one would have to apply a correction of -32 meters in order to calculate the correct altitude.  (*Note:corrections are negative so you would actually be subtracting a negative and thus shifting the reading up 32 meters*).

As opposed to Android it is our understanding that with regards to coreLocation this GeoidHeight information is automagically calculated internally by IOS.  Where we are running into difficulty is that we are using a local wifi network with a sensor that calculates uncorrected GPS and collecting both the external sensor data as well as coreLocation readings for GPS.  I was wondering if anybody was aware of a library (C/Objective-C) which has the Geoid information and can help me do these calculations on the fly when I'm reading the raw GPS signal from our sensor package.

Thank you for your help.

*Side note:  Please don't suggest I look at the following post: **[Get altitude by longitude and latitude in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998/android-get-altitude-by-longitude-and-latitude)** This si a good solution however we do not have a live internet connection so we cannot make a live query to Goole or USGS.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gone ahead and solved my problems here.  What I did was create an ObjectiveC implementation of a c implementation of fortran code to do what I needed.  The original c can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/egm96-f477-c/

You would need to download the project from source forge in order to access the input files required for this code:  **CORCOEF** and **EGM96**

My objective-c implementation is as follows:

**GeoidCalculator.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GeoidCalculator : NSObject
+ (GeoidCalculator *)instance;


-(double) getHeightFromLat:(double)lat    andLon:(double)lon;
-(double) getCurrentHeightOffset;
-(void) updatePositionWithLatitude:(double)lat andLongitude:(double)lon;

@end
```

**GeoidCalculator.m**

```
#import "GeoidCalculator.h"
#import <stdio.h>
#import <math.h>


#define l_value    (65341)
#define _361    (361)

@implementation GeoidCalculator

static int nmax;

static double currentHeight;

static double cc[l_value+ 1], cs[l_value+ 1], hc[l_value+ 1], hs[l_value+ 1],
        p[l_value+ 1], sinml[_361+ 1], cosml[_361+ 1], rleg[_361+ 1];

+ (GeoidCalculator *)instance {
    static GeoidCalculator *_instance = nil;

    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_instance == nil) {
            _instance = [[self alloc] init];
            init_arrays();
            currentHeight = -9999;
        }
    }

    return _instance;
}


- (double)getHeightFromLat:(double)lat andLon:(double)lon {
    [self updatePositionWithLatitude:lat andLongitude:lon];
    return [self getCurrentHeightOffset];
}


- (double)getCurrentHeightOffset {
    return currentHeight;
}

- (void)updatePositionWithLatitude:(double)lat andLongitude:(double)lon {
    const double rad = 180 / M_PI;
    double flat, flon, u;
    flat = lat; flon = lon;

    /*compute the geocentric latitude,geocentric radius,normal gravity*/
    u = undulation(flat / rad, flon / rad, nmax, nmax + 1);

    /*u is the geoid undulation from the egm96 potential coefficient model
       including the height anomaly to geoid undulation correction term
       and a correction term to have the undulations refer to the
       wgs84 ellipsoid. the geoid undulation unit is meters.*/
    currentHeight = u;
}


double hundu(unsigned nmax, double p[l_value+ 1],
        double hc[l_value+ 1], double hs[l_value+ 1],
        double sinml[_361+ 1], double cosml[_361+ 1], double gr, double re,
        double cc[l_value+ 1], double cs[l_value+ 1]) {/*constants for wgs84(g873);gm in units of m**3/s**2*/
    const double gm = .3986004418e15, ae = 6378137.;
    double arn, ar, ac, a, b, sum, sumc, sum2, tempc, temp;
    int k, n, m;
    ar = ae / re;
    arn = ar;
    ac = a = b = 0;
    k = 3;
    for (n = 2; n <= nmax; n++) {
        arn *= ar;
        k++;
        sum = p[k] * hc[k];
        sumc = p[k] * cc[k];
        sum2 = 0;
        for (m = 1; m <= n; m++) {
            k++;
            tempc = cc[k] * cosml[m] + cs[k] * sinml[m];
            temp = hc[k] * cosml[m] + hs[k] * sinml[m];
            sumc += p[k] * tempc;
            sum += p[k] * temp;
        }
        ac += sumc;
        a += sum * arn;
    }
    ac += cc[1] + p[2] * cc[2] + p[3] * (cc[3] * cosml[1] + cs[3] * sinml[1]);
/*add haco=ac/100 to convert height anomaly on the ellipsoid to the undulation
add -0.53m to make undulation refer to the wgs84 ellipsoid.*/
    return a * gm / (gr * re) + ac / 100 - .53;
}

void dscml(double rlon, unsigned nmax, double sinml[_361+ 1], double cosml[_361+ 1]) {
    double a, b;
    int m;
    a = sin(rlon);
    b = cos(rlon);
    sinml[1] = a;
    cosml[1] = b;
    sinml[2] = 2 * b * a;
    cosml[2] = 2 * b * b - 1;
    for (m = 3; m <= nmax; m++) {
        sinml[m] = 2 * b * sinml[m - 1] - sinml[m - 2];
        cosml[m] = 2 * b * cosml[m - 1] - cosml[m - 2];
    }
}

void dhcsin(unsigned nmax, double hc[l_value+ 1], double hs[l_value+ 1]) {


    // potential coefficient file
    //f_12 = fopen("EGM96", "rb");
    NSString* path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EGM96" ofType:@""];
    FILE* f_12 = fopen(path2.UTF8String, "rb");
    if (f_12 == NULL) {
        NSLog([path2 stringByAppendingString:@" not found"]);
    }



    int n, m;
    double j2, j4, j6, j8, j10, c, s, ec, es;
/*the even degree zonal coefficients given below were computed for the
 wgs84(g873) system of constants and are identical to those values
 used in the NIMA gridding procedure. computed using subroutine
 grs written by N.K. PAVLIS*/
    j2 = 0.108262982131e-2;
    j4 = -.237091120053e-05;
    j6 = 0.608346498882e-8;
    j8 = -0.142681087920e-10;
    j10 = 0.121439275882e-13;
    m = ((nmax + 1) * (nmax + 2)) / 2;
    for (n = 1; n <= m; n++)hc[n] = hs[n] = 0;
    while (6 == fscanf(f_12, "%i %i %lf %lf %lf %lf", &n, &m, &c, &s, &ec, &es)) {
        if (n > nmax)continue;
        n = (n * (n + 1)) / 2 + m + 1;
        hc[n] = c;
        hs[n] = s;
    }
    hc[4] += j2 / sqrt(5);
    hc[11] += j4 / 3;
    hc[22] += j6 / sqrt(13);
    hc[37] += j8 / sqrt(17);
    hc[56] += j10 / sqrt(21);


    fclose(f_12);

}

void legfdn(unsigned m, double theta, double rleg[_361+ 1], unsigned nmx)
/*this subroutine computes  all normalized legendre function
in "rleg". order is always
m, and colatitude is always theta  (radians). maximum deg
is  nmx. all calculations in double precision.
ir  must be set to zero before the first call to this sub.
the dimensions of arrays  rleg must be at least equal to  nmx+1.
Original programmer :Oscar L. Colombo, Dept. of Geodetic Science
the Ohio State University, August 1980
ineiev: I removed the derivatives, for they are never computed here*/
{
    static double drts[1301], dirt[1301], cothet, sithet, rlnn[_361+ 1];
    static int ir;
    int nmx1 = nmx + 1, nmx2p = 2 * nmx + 1, m1 = m + 1, m2 = m + 2, m3 = m + 3, n, n1, n2;
    if (!ir) {
        ir = 1;
        for (n = 1; n <= nmx2p; n++) {
            drts[n] = sqrt(n);
            dirt[n] = 1 / drts[n];
        }
    }
    cothet = cos(theta);
    sithet = sin(theta);
    /*compute the legendre functions*/
    rlnn[1] = 1;
    rlnn[2] = sithet * drts[3];
    for (n1 = 3; n1 <= m1; n1++) {
        n = n1 - 1;
        n2 = 2 * n;
        rlnn[n1] = drts[n2 + 1] * dirt[n2] * sithet * rlnn[n];
    }
    switch (m) {
        case 1:
            rleg[2] = rlnn[2];
            rleg[3] = drts[5] * cothet * rleg[2];
            break;
        case 0:
            rleg[1] = 1;
            rleg[2] = cothet * drts[3];
            break;
    }
    rleg[m1] = rlnn[m1];
    if (m2 <= nmx1) {
        rleg[m2] = drts[m1 * 2 + 1] * cothet * rleg[m1];
        if (m3 <= nmx1)
            for (n1 = m3; n1 <= nmx1; n1++) {
                n = n1 - 1;
                if ((!m && n < 2) || (m == 1 && n < 3))continue;
                n2 = 2 * n;
                rleg[n1] = drts[n2 + 1] * dirt[n + m] * dirt[n - m] *
                        (drts[n2 - 1] * cothet * rleg[n1 - 1] - drts[n + m - 1] * drts[n - m - 1] * dirt[n2 - 3] * rleg[n1 - 2]);
            }
    }
}

void radgra(double lat, double lon, double *rlat, double *gr, double *re)
/*this subroutine computes geocentric distance to the point,
the geocentric latitude,and
an approximate value of normal gravity at the point based
the constants of the wgs84(g873) system are used*/
{
    const double a = 6378137., e2 = .00669437999013, geqt = 9.7803253359, k = .00193185265246;
    double n, t1 = sin(lat) * sin(lat), t2, x, y, z;
    n = a / sqrt(1 - e2 * t1);
    t2 = n * cos(lat);
    x = t2 * cos(lon);
    y = t2 * sin(lon);
    z = (n * (1 - e2)) * sin(lat);
    *re = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);/*compute the geocentric radius*/
    *rlat = atan(z / sqrt(x * x + y * y));/*compute the geocentric latitude*/
    *gr = geqt * (1 + k * t1) / sqrt(1 - e2 * t1);/*compute normal gravity:units are m/sec**2*/
}


double undulation(double lat, double lon, int nmax, int k) {
    double rlat, gr, re;
    int i, j, m;
    radgra(lat, lon, &rlat, &gr, &re);
    rlat = M_PI / 2 - rlat;
    for (j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
        m = j - 1;
        legfdn(m, rlat, rleg, nmax);
        for (i = j; i <= k; i++)p[(i - 1) * i / 2 + m + 1] = rleg[i];
    }
    dscml(lon, nmax, sinml, cosml);
    return hundu(nmax, p, hc, hs, sinml, cosml, gr, re, cc, cs);
}

void init_arrays(void) {
    int ig, i, n, m;
    double t1, t2;






    NSString* path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CORCOEF" ofType:@""];


    //correction coefficient file:  modified with 'sed -e"s/D/e/g"' to be read with fscanf
    FILE* f_1 = fopen([path1 cStringUsingEncoding:1], "rb");
    if (f_1 == NULL) {
        NSLog([path1 stringByAppendingString:@" not found"]);
    }


    nmax = 360;
    for (i = 1; i <= l_value; i++)cc[i] = cs[i] = 0;

    while (4 == fscanf(f_1, "%i %i %lg %lg", &n, &m, &t1, &t2)) {
        ig = (n * (n + 1)) / 2 + m + 1;
        cc[ig] = t1;
        cs[ig] = t2;
    }
/*the correction coefficients are now read in*/
/*the potential coefficients are now read in and the reference
 even degree zonal harmonic coefficients removed to degree 6*/
    dhcsin(nmax, hc, hs);
    fclose(f_1);
}


@end
```

I've done some limited testing against the Geoid Height Calculator (http://www.unavco.org/community_science/science-support/geoid/geoid.html) and looks like everything is a match

## UPDATE iOS8 or Greater

As of IOS8 This code might not work correctly.  You may need to change how the bundle is loaded:

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EGM96" ofType:@""];`

Do some googling or add a comment here.

Comment: Thanks.  This is really only relevant when you are working with external GPS sensors as the iPhone does this internally already.

Comment: on ios, you would need it to convert the geoid height to WGS84 ellipsoid which is normally the standard. (if one want to export data in WGS84 altitude, too)

Comment: We have a sensor that puts out RAW GPS altitude and are trying to compare it to CoreLocation - so this routine is required.  Also for another point of confusion EGM96 = WGS84 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)

Answer (score 3):

Impressive stuff Jeef!  I just used your code to create this sqlite which may be easier to add/use in a project, assuming integer precision for lat/lon is good enough:

https://github.com/vectorstofinal/geoid_heights

Comment: Just this:  GeoidCalculator * calc = [GeoidCalculator instance];
    
    NSInteger resolution = 1; // lat/lon degrees
    
    for ( int lat = -90; lat <= 90; lat += resolution) {
        for ( int lon = -180; lon <= 180; lon += resolution) {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", @(lat), @(lon), @([calc getHeightFromLat:lat andLon:lon]) );
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could use GeoTrans.

Provided by http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/geotrans/index.html

The keyword is "vertical datum". So you want to convert from WGS84 to e.g EGM96 vertical datum. Make sure which Geoid modell you want to use. EGM96 is one of that.

Maybe these answer help you, too:
[How to calculate the altitude above from mean sea level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249193/how-to-calculate-the-altitude-above-from-mean-sea-level/12811478#12811478)

Next read the ios Open Source License Text: Available in

```
Settings -> General -> About -> Legal -> License ...
```

There you get a list of all libs that ios uses. One of them I found was the calculation of magnetic decilination usung a sw of USGS. Chances are verry high that the Geoid height calculation is listed there too.

Comment: On the phone I don't se a settings -> general -> info menu.  I do see settings - general - about - legal - license

Comment: I found it too time consuming to try to port the C++ library of geotrans over to Objective-c

Comment: If the hint to EGM96 did help you, consider an upvote.