# Have a "geoid" infomation in documentation of CoreLocation?

Tags: ios, core-location

I have learned somewhere that the value returned by the "altitude" property of CoreLocation contains the [geoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid) difference in the calculation.

However, I could not find a description in Apple's official document that shows its basis:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423820-altitude

Is the description of geoid in altitude of CoreLocation not written in the official document?

Additional Question:
Does altitude including Geoid apply to any location all over the world?

Comment: Are you looking for [`CMAltimeter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmaltimeter)?

Comment: Yes, that means yours.

Comment: Will this help? [WGS84 Geoid Height Altitude Offset for external GPS data on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22196714)

Comment: @Pang It is about the handling of Geoid when using external GPS data. I would like to know about the value measured directly by CoreLocation.

Comment: It is not about CMAltimeter but about the altitude property of CoreLocation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423820-altitude

Comment: Seems not mentioned anyway in Apple's docs: https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Adeveloper.apple.com%20geoid

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a reference link from Apple since I never found one. But I can say from testing that early iPhone models did NOT correct for geoid, while all models since the iPhone 4 ans all iPad models DO correct for geoid.
And yes, AFAIK, the correction is valid worldwide.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fantastic question and one that I wish had a solid answer, I have seen a few posts that seem to indicate that iOS is using EGM96 or a similar global geoid model as the reference geoid but this has has no official documentation from Apple as far as I can tell.

The following post in the Apple Developer Forums seems to back this up https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/95874.

This is information that Apple really needs to make available in some way.