Android location mean sea level not set
I want to access the mean sea level of an location using .NET MAUI with native Android calls:
Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>().Wait();
var locationManager = (LocationManager)MauiApplication.Current
    .GetSystemService(Context.LocationService)!;
    
var location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
var mslLocation = location.MslAltitudeMeters;

But this results in an Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'The Mean Sea Level altitude of this location is not set.'.
I also tried using RequestLocationUpdates:
locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 100L, 0f, new LocationListener());


class LocationListener : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationListener
{
    public void OnLocationChanged(global::Android.Locations.Location location)
    {
        var mslLocation = location.MslAltitudeMeters;
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {

    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {

    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string? provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle? extras)
    {

    }
}

I have the following AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>

In both cases msl location is not available. Am i missing something? Are there any permissions required? I could not find anything in the official documentation for the Location class in Java

Have you tried calling hasMslAltitude() ?

have you used other tools to verify that the device can actually provide this data?

You might also look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76146209/115145 for some ideas of a fallback way to get this data.

@CommonsWare hasMslAltitude returns false
Is msl altitude not supported by all devices with Android 14 or higher?

@Jason No, i only checked my Android version (14)
Are there any tool i could use for that?

"Is msl altitude not supported by all devices with Android 14 or higher?" -- probably not. That may be up to the manufacturer. If they bother with methods like hasMslAltitude(), usually there is a reason.

not offhand, but I"m sure there are many different GPS apps that you could use to confirm

@Jason But how would i know if an app is showing the msl data from android api and not something calculated by it self?

Beats me.  But if they can calculate it, why can't you?  But as others have said, this seems like a hardware feature that many devices may not provide.

Yeah, it will probably come down to this, but that's exactly what i tried to avoid
